# Cómo hacer center-align en un elemento flex y right-align para otro con Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.box { 
     display:flex;
     justify-content:center;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: blue;
   }

 .item1{
     flex:1;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     font-size:5rem;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: coral;
   }

 .item2{
     font-size:2rem;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: yellow;
   }
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="item1">
   <div>99.999.00</div>

 </div>
 <div class="item2">99.999.00</div>
 </div>
```

Cómo puedo alinear con flexbox dos items uno al centro y otro alineado a la derecha, pero el que está al centro lo haga sobre el 100% del ancho de la página y no del espacio restante.

Lo estoy haciendo así como muestro abajo, pero el item que está al centro es más grande y va a quedar hacia la izquierda respecto al total del ancho de la página.

Quiero que el número grande **"item1"** esté centrado respecto al cuadro azul. y el número pequeño **item2** esté centrado respecto al cuadro amarillo, alguna idea?, gracias.

[image: Imagen ejemplo]

```html
 <div class="box">
 <div class="item1">
   <div>99.999.00</div>

 </div>
 <div class="item2">99.999.00</div>
 </div>
```

```css
  .box { 
     display:flex;
     justify-content:center;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: blue;
   }

 .item1{
     flex:1;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     font-size:5rem;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: coral;
   }

 .item2{
     font-size:2rem;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: yellow;
   }
```

https://jsbin.com/tivenoj/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Una opcion es poner un clon del de la derecha a la izquierda con opacidad 0 y da la sensacion que está centrado en relacion al medio.

Answer (score 0):

Agreta esto al .item2:

```
.item2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Si no es lo que quieres, muestra una imagen del diseño final de como quedaría el contenedor.

EDITO:
Creo que en base a lo que entendí, quieres algo parecido a esto, No se si los borders los colocaste a modo de muestra o si son parte de la maquetación, si es así puedes ajustarlo para que aparezcan en los contenedores editados:

```css
 .box { 
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: blue;
}
.items {
  width: 100%;
}
.item1{
   flex:1;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   font-size:5rem;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: coral;
}

.item2{
   font-size:2rem;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: yellow;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: end;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="items item0">
    </div>
    
    <div class="items item1">
      <div>99.999.00</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="items item2">
      <div>99.999.00</div>
    </div>
</div>
```